# Преобразование типов к собственным С++

Tags: c++, типы

Не могу разобраться как преобразовать типы данных. В моем случае из строки в тип TElement.

Допустим есть Класс TSpisok, в нем функция AddElement принимающая TElement *e в качестве параметра

```
class TElement
{
public:
   TElement *next,*prev;
};
class TSpisok
{
TElement *first,*last,*cur;
public:
   TSpisok() {
    first = last = cur = NULL;
  };

  class TNumber : TElement {
    public: int num;
    TNumber(int n): TElement(),
    num(n) {}
  };

  class TString : TElement {
    public: char str[20];
    TString(char s[20]): TElement() {
        strcpy(str, s);
    }
  };

   void AddElement (TElement *e)
   {
   //что то делается
   };
   void ShowList (int index)
   {
       cur = first;
       while (cur != NULL) {
       Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(cur);
   }
   };
}
```

По нажатию кнопки нужно передать в функцию AddElement значение из текстобокса, т.е. строку типа String\Char

```
TElement * p;

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
char * st;
int k;
st = new char[20];
st = Edit1->Text.c_str();
if (strstr(st, "") != NULL) {
            k = atoi(st);
            if (k || (strlen(st) == 1 && st[0] == '0'))
                        p = new TNumber(k);
            else p = new TString(st);
            Spisok.AddElement(p);
        }
    }
```

и как вывести элемент списка на ListBox в форме?

```
   void ShowList (int index)
      {
           cur = first;
           while (cur != NULL) {
           Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(cur);
           }

      };
```

На что получаю ошибку. Вопрос, как грамотно передавать параметры?

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(65): E2034 Cannot convert 'TElement *' to 'AnsiString'

Comment: если вы пытаетесь реализовать список, то в классе элемента, помимо указателей на следующий и предыдущий элемент, должно быть поле, которое хранит в себе какие-либо данные

Comment: именно его и пытаюсь, поля имеются в дочерних классах для вводимых строки\числа соответственно. Решил не добавлять это сюда чтобы не загромождать

Comment: лучше добавьте, лучше более информативно, нежели сжато и непонятно

Comment: Добавил все что имеется

Comment: Действительно...Спасибо. Я бы еще сутки так просидел

Comment: теперь не могу разобраться как обратно вывести элемент из списка на форму. Опять та же ошибка "Cannot convert 'TElement *' to 'AnsiString'"

Answer (score 1):

`class TNumber : TElement {...}` означает закрытое наследование, которое подразумевает, что наследуемый класс лишь может использовать открытые и защищенные члены базового. Только   функции_члены этого класса и друзья класса могут преобразовать   указатель класса  в указатель базового. Поэтому, если вы хотите во внешней функции делать это, то следует наследовать открыто: `class TNumber : public TElement {...}` или же `struct TNumber : TElement {...}`. По хорошему все ваши сущности структуры...

Comment: _"По хорошему все ваши сущности структуры..."_ - не понял.

Comment: @Qwertiy, имеется ввиду что, если такие элементы обьектной модели, как инкапсуляция и абстрагирование, отсутствуют, а есть лишь открытая коллекция данных, то это лучше записать как структура, Так и понятней и меньше писанины.